# provideRouter and RouterConfig not found in new @angular/router 3.0.0-alpha.3^

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular, npm, angular2-routing

I am migrating an angular2 app to RC2 and trying to use the router's version 3 alpha.

I have followed the set up of the [plunker given](http://plnkr.co/edit/ER0tf8fpGHZiuVWB7Q07?p=preview) by the [angular docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html) for routing
 But i keep getting the following errors:

> /@angular/router/index"' has no exported member 'provideRouter'
>
> /@angular/router/index"' has no exported member 'RouterConfig'

when trying to use the following imports in my app.router.ts file:

```
import { provideRouter, RouterConfig } from '@angular/router';
```

I am using typescript in visual studio with commonjs module format.

Here are the dependecies from my packages.json

```
"@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.2",
"@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.2",
"@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.2",
"@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.2",
"@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.2",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.2",
"@angular/router": "3.0.0-alpha.3",
"@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.2",
"@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.2",
"systemjs": "0.19.27",
"core-js": "^2.4.0",
"reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
"rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
"zone.js": "^0.6.12",
"angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.12"
```

Even if I set the angular/route to the npm cdn in my system.config.js like so:

> '@angular/router': 'https://npmcdn.com/@angular/router@3.0.0-alpha.3'

I still get the error.

I even tried using the alpha.4, alpha.5 and latest alpha.6 version.

I tried deleting the nodule module folder and forcing the npm install to get new files.

QUESTION:

Can someone help me figure out why the exported memebers **provideRouter**, **RouterConfig** can not be found?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had the same issue, solved it with using Version 3.0.0-alpha.7

Here my package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/common":  "2.0.0-rc.2",
"@angular/compiler":  "2.0.0-rc.2",
"@angular/core":  "2.0.0-rc.2",
"@angular/http":  "2.0.0-rc.2",
"@angular/platform-browser":  "2.0.0-rc.2",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic":  "2.0.0-rc.2",
"@angular/router":  "3.0.0-alpha.7",
"@angular/upgrade":  "2.0.0-rc.2",
"systemjs": "0.19.31",
"core-js": "^2.4.0",
"reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
"rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
"zone.js": "^0.6.12",
"angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.12",
"bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
"contentful": "3.3.14"}
```

Altough I wouldn't call it stable and the new Documentation https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html can be bit missleading.

Comment: Thanks chriisi, looks like it was the systemjs version - meeded to update to 0.19.31 from 0.19.27 with alpha 7 worked

Comment: I now downgraded on Alpha6, since Alpha7 always brought me an error: "Path can not start with a slash".
Now it's working like a charm.

Comment: thanks, i came across some other errors, I just don't think its stable enough for me right now.  I'm going to come back to it once its better integrated with RC2

Comment: yeah understandable. the only motivation is, that it could be the final builds. don't wanna build the whole application in router-deprecated and change everything in a month.

Comment: exactly, the joys of working with release candidates of front end frameworks ;)

Comment: I'd expect a "release candidate" to be more stable :) Anyway, router beta7 is broken and always gives "Path can not start with a slash" error, beta6 works fine.

Comment: I updated same as your package,json but for me is not working, same error: angular/router/index"' has no exported mng 'ROUTER_PROVIDERS'

Comment: and remember to run npm update (not npm install) after package.json change

Answer (score 6):

Try to use provideRoutes instead of provideRouter

```
import {provideRoutes} from "@angular/router";
```

and your routing:

```
provideRoutes([
    {path: '', redirectTo: '/myurl'}
])
```

**UPD**
For now you don't need provideRouters at all. Just write path and import 
Routes from '@angular/router';

```
import {RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';

const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [
  {path: '', redirectTo: '/somthng', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: 'somthng', component: SomthngComponent},
  {path: 'somthng-list', component: SomthngListComponent}
];

export const your_routing = RouterModule.forRoot(APP_ROUTES);
```

Answer (score 1):

Also wrestled with this for a few hours, upgraded to beta7. Remember to change system.config.js as they changed packagenames to index.js (e.g. "platform-browser-dynamic/platform-browser-dynamic.js" is now named "platform-browser-dynamic/index.js".

But now I can't seem to get a default route to work, is it ''?

EDIT: Default routing is simply:

```
{
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'index.php/component/atkstat/dashboard'
},
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add this line as @angular/router No umd for router yet

```
packages['@angular/router'] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
```

Have a look package.json and system.config.js of this is , may help you

http://plnkr.co/edit/y31K7xbiQSVH59qsAOZF?p=preview