# angular-meteor meteor node_modules/@angular/router/index has no exported member 'provideRouter'

Tags: meteor, typescript, angular, angular2-routing, angular-meteor

## Issue

I am using angular2 with meteor and trying to move to router 3 from router-deprecated.
I have been following the tutorial on https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html
I keep getting the following error when I run meteor:
Module '"node_modules/@angular/router/index"' has no exported member 'provideRouter'

## Fixes tried

I have removed all old router modules and installed the newest one after finding this issue but nothing has changed
I have also deleted and re-installed all of node_modules and then every router package I have used.

I also am using the latest version and have tried the solution in [provideRouter and RouterConfig not found in new @angular/router 3.0.0-alpha.3^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37886276/providerouter-and-routerconfig-not-found-in-new-angular-router-3-0-0-alpha-3)

## Environment

I am using Meteor with Angular2 and TypeScript to build a basic web browser application