# angular2 src/app/app.routing"' has no exported member 'routing'

Tags: angular, npm, router

This is my packages.json:

```
{
  "name": "ng2",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ng serve",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/forms": "0.3.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.5",

    "@angular/router":  "3.0.0-alpha.7",
    "es6-shim": "0.35.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "systemjs": "0.19.26",
    "zone.js": "0.6.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.10",
    "codelyzer": "0.0.20",
    "ember-cli-inject-live-reload": "1.4.0",
    "jasmine-core": "2.4.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "0.13.22",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "0.2.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "0.3.8",
    "protractor": "3.3.0",
    "ts-node": "0.5.5",
    "tslint": "3.11.0",
    "typescript": "1.8.10",
    "typings": "1.3.1"
  }
}
```

generated by `angular cli`

I run `npm install` and `npm update`

but when I run `napm start` I get this error on `localhost:4200`

```
  /Users/eladb/WorkspaceQa/SupporTool/src/main/webapp/html/ng2/tmp/broccoli_type_script_compiler-input_base_path-RQyxga2K.tmp/0/src/app/app.module.ts (6, 9): Module '"/Users/eladb/WorkspaceQa/SupporTool/src/main/webapp/html/ng2/tmp/broccoli_type_script_compiler-input_base_path-RQyxga2K.tmp/0/src/app/app.routing"' has no exported member 'routing'.
  /Users/eladb/WorkspaceQa/SupporTool/src/main/webapp/html/ng2/tmp/broccoli_type_script_compiler-input_base_path-RQyxga2K.tmp/0/src/app/app.routing.ts (2, 10): Module '"/Users/eladb/WorkspaceQa/SupporTool/src/main/webapp/html/ng2/node_modules/@angular/router/index"' has no exported member 'Routes'.
  /Users/eladb/WorkspaceQa/SupporTool/src/main/webapp/html/ng2/tmp/broccoli_type_script_compiler-input_base_path-RQyxga2K.tmp/0/src/app/app.routing.ts (2, 18): Module '"/Users/eladb/WorkspaceQa/SupporTool/src/main/webapp/html/ng2/node_modules/@angular/router/index"' has no exported member 'RouterModule'.
  /Users/eladb/WorkspaceQa/SupporTool/src/main/webapp/html/ng2/tmp/broccoli_type_script_compiler-input_base_path-RQyxga2K.tmp/0/src/app/app.routing.ts (4, 38): Cannot find module './heroes.component'.
    at BroccoliTypeScriptCompiler._doIncrementalBuild (/Users/eladb/WorkspaceQa/SupporTool/src/main/webapp/html/ng2/node_modules/angular-cli/lib/broccoli/broccoli-typescript.js:120:19)
    at BroccoliTypeScriptCompiler.build (/Users/eladb/WorkspaceQa/SupporTool/src/main/webapp/html/ng2/node_modules/angular-cli/lib/broccoli/broccoli-typescript.js:43:10)
    at /Users/eladb/WorkspaceQa/SupporTool/src/main/webapp/html/ng2/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/broccoli-caching-writer/index.js:152:21
    at lib$rsvp$$internal$$tryCatch (/Users/eladb/WorkspaceQa/SupporTool/src/main/webapp/html/ng2/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:1036:16)
    at lib$rsvp$$internal$$invokeCallback (/Users/eladb/WorkspaceQa/SupporTool/src/main/webapp/html/ng2/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:1048:17)
    at lib$rsvp$$internal$$publish (/Users/eladb/WorkspaceQa/SupporTool/src/main/webapp/html/ng2/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:1019:11)
    at lib$rsvp$asap$$flush (/Users/eladb/WorkspaceQa/SupporTool/src/main/webapp/html/ng2/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:1198:9)
```

according to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37886276/providerouter-and-routerconfig-not-found-in-new-angular-router-3-0-0-alpha-3), my package is OK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define `routing` yourself. It's usually a variable that refers to the routing module configured with routes like for example

```
export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

For more details see https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html